# More concise form to set a read-only `@property` in python

Tags: python, properties, decorator, public, python-decorators

I know that if I want to set a read-only property in python I can do the following in a class:

```
class Foo(object):

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo
```

but it seems still too long (3/4 lines) in the case I have many of properties as simple as this one.

I know I could code a system myself to create read-only properties, but I would like to avoid to reinvent the wheel.

I am wondering if there are special functions that can do something like:

```
create_ro_property(self,"foo","_foo",42) # where 42 is the initial value of 42
```

This would create a read-only property `foo` that can be set internally to the object via `_foo`.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
class Foo(object):

    foo = property(lambda self: self._foo)
```

The `@` is just syntactic sugar and a `lambda` can replace such a trivial `def` for creating the getter.

Note that this doesn't set the initial value of `42`; you would still have to do that e.g. in `__init__`. Alternatively, perhaps you could do something clever in `__getattr__` to return `None` for missing attributes starting with `_`, then make the return value `self._foo or 42` (or, if `0` is a valid value, `42 if self._foo is None else self._foo`).